# Corrupted windows form in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, corruption

VS froze while I was using it, and now whenever I try to open it in the designer, it freezes again, and when I build and run I get no errors. I call the form from my program, THEN it freezes, so it is just That one form, nothing else. I can't post the code because it's 200+ lines, and my laptop can't connect to internet :(

Comment: perhaps 'clean solution' or alternatively create a new project and dump the old code into the new one, see if it's the form itself, or something tied to the solution/project.

Comment: Clean didn't work, trying other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the [.suo file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx) associated with your project. A lot of times that will get corrupted and cause the problem that you have. I just noticed that you are able to open your project. Try putting a breakpoint on your `InitializeComponent()` for the form to see what component is causing your problem.

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu I added another option to try.

Comment: Ok, using break points in the InitializeComponent, I narrowed it down to here: this.messageReader1 = new ZzChat.MessageReader();  which is the name of a custom, user control

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu Is it a control that you wrote, or a third party control. If you wrote it set a breakpoint on your constructor. If you didn't delete it in the form designer's code behind and add it again.

Comment: Its my control, I finally got it to work when you run the program, but VS still freezes when I open the designer

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu You are probably doing some action with the control that the designer doesn't like. Try using the DesignMode Property to check when you are in the Designer and not do what is locking up your form.

Comment: i tried it in many places and it doesnt work...is there any way to put breakpoints that show up when you add the controls to the designer instead of having to run it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9007/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-efe-ozturkoglu)